# Does constant velocity of center of mass imply linear momentum is conserved?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

I know that if momentum is conserved for a system, you can derive that the velocity of the center of mass of that system is constant. I was wondering if the second condition also implies the first: if I can demonstrate that the velocity of the center of mass of a system is constant, does that imply that linear momentum is conserved in the system?

Comment: Assuming that the system does not lose mass, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The linear momentum of a system is given by $\vec{p} = m \vec{v}$.

If you differentiate this with respect to time in an inertial frame, you have:

$$
{d\vec{p} \over dt} = m {d\vec{v} \over dt} + {dm\over dt} \vec{v}
$$

If $\vec{v}$ is constant with time, this becomes

$$
{d\vec{p} \over dt} = {dm\over dt} \vec{v}
$$

Which means, for $d\vec{p}/dt$ to be zero (or $\vec{p}$ to be constant), you must have at least one of $\vec{v}$ or $dm/dt$ equal to zero.

Which means, either your object doesn't move at all, or, if it is moving, doesn't lose or gain any mass.

Comment: @glance, The question asks for linear momentum, so I've limited my answer to linear momentum. The rotation of a body gives it angular momentum, which is _not_ linear momentum.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you assumption is correct, for an isolated system, conervation of linear momentum is equivalent to the velocity of the center of mass being constant. The term with variable mass from another answer is incorrect. You can only have variable mass in a non-isolated sysrtem.